# How to get MAX value for a given week having data per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure if the title is readable enough, will try to explain it better here

I have data in the following schema:

```
ID     | Date         | Unit1 | Hours | TENURE_Hours    
"Alex" | '2018-11-04' |    21 |    12 | 134
"Adam" | '2018-11-04' |    21 |    26 | 156
"John" | '2018-11-04' |    21 |    32 | 122
"Alex" | '2018-11-06' |    21 |    67 | 146
"Adam" | '2018-11-06' |    21 |    74 | 182
"John" | '2018-11-06' |    21 |    45 | 154
"Alex" | '2018-11-11' |    21 |    22 | 213
"Adam" | '2018-11-11' |    21 |    22 | 256
"John" | '2018-11-11' |    21 |    22 | 199
```

And what I would like to achieve is to have the split per week number with the highest number in the week

I tried to use `MAX()`, but it returns the highest value within the whole range, if I try to pull data for previous 10 months ,it will return the highest value for this period of time, not specific week.

In the above example I would like to have:

```
Week | ID     | TENURE_Hours

45   | "Alex" | 146
45   | "Adam" | 182
45   | "John" | 154

46   | "Alex" | 213
46   | "Adam" | 256
46   | "John" | 199
```

What do you think? Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, but I think this problem can be solved in every SQL engine

Thanks in advance

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: The problem can be solved in every SQL engine, but functions, especially date functions are very different for different dbms.  It's useless if someone is posting MySQL or Oracle code if you're using SQL Server, so tag your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select year(date) as yyyy, datepart(week, date) as wk, id, max(tenure_hours)
from t
group by year(date), datepart(week, date), id
order by yyyy, wk, id;
```